# Redefining proof environment

Tags: formatting, environments, amsthm

How can I change the `\begin{proof}` environment so that the word `Proof` which is displayed in my document isn't italic? I tried changing `\proofname`, but that only changes the displayed text, not the style.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will! If you are using the [amsthm package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) then `\begin{proof}[\textbf{Proof}]...\end{proof}` should put proof in bold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're talking about `proof` as defined by `amsthm`. The command `\itshape` is hardwired in the environment's definition.

I suggest patching it so it uses a “generic” command that you can redefine at will:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\normalfont\proofnamefont}{}{}

\newcommand{\proofnamefont}{} % add nothing
```

Full example. The `\renewcommand` is just for testing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\normalfont\proofnamefont}{}{}

\newcommand{\proofnamefont}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Obvious, isn't it?
\end{proof}

\renewcommand{\proofnamefont}{\bfseries}

\begin{proof}[Proof in boldface]
Test for boldface and the optional argument.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just to clear up things: if you want boldface, the code should be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\normalfont\proofnamefont}{}{}

\newcommand{\proofnamefont}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Obvious, isn't it?
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Nicholas I added the `amsthm` tag, so surely our friend Barbara Beeton will take notice of the feature request.

Comment: request posted, but as a request to add \proofnamefont rather than hard-coded \itshape.  in fact, there is a generic request on file to reconsider *all* hard-coded font settings (except perhaps for italic for the basic theorem environment, although even there i know some people who prefer slanted type).

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have no objection to just `\proofnamefont`.