# Why the Q.E.D. symbol show after the sentence end and can't show right aligned (as picture below)?

Tags: symbols, theorems, proof-package

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,papersize={15.5cm,23.5cm}]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesection\arabic{theorem}}
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\noindent\bfseries Proof.}}{\qedsymbol}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{ABC}
    blablabla
    \section{ONE}
    \begin{theorem}
        dddd
    \end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
    It is clear.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

I want the text **Proof** is bold. So I write:

```
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\noindent\bfseries Proof.}}{\qedsymbol}
```

Now, I want to Q.E.D. symbol is black square, so I write

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
```

Why the Q.E.D. symbol show after the sentence end and can't show right aligned (as picture below)? How to make it?

[image]

I want:

[image]

Comment: `\renewenvironment{proof}{{\noindent\bfseries Proof.}}{\qedsymbol}` has completely removed all the definition of the proof environment and its placement of the header and of the qed symbol, the end code just dumps the symbol as if you had written `\qedsymbol` at the end of the text.

Comment: Why are you redefining `proof` to begin with? If it's just in order to get “Proof” in boldface, there are much better methods: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251251/4427

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion is to use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251251/4427 with also a redefinition of `\qedsymbol`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\providecommand{\proofnamefont}{\itshape}% the default
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\normalfont\proofnamefont}{}{}
\renewcommand{\proofnamefont}{\bfseries}% your preference

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Obvious, isn't it?
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

From your `MWE`, came to understand that you need the `Proof` name in `Bold` face and the `qedsymbol` should be in solid black square, for that no need to redefine the `proof` environment, you can modify the `\proofname` and `\qedsymbol` as you wish, and the modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,papersize={15.5cm,23.5cm}]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesection\arabic{theorem}}
%\renewenvironment{proof}{{\noindent\bfseries Proof.}}{\qedsymbol}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\upshape\textbf{Proof}}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{ABC}
    blablabla
    \section{ONE}
    \begin{theorem}
        dddd
    \end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
    It is clear.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

And the output is:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can redefine the `\proofname` and `\qedsymbol` as folows. It's not necessary to create a black square by the rule command since there is a `\blacksquare` command in the `amssymb` package which could produce a black square as the same size as the (white) square.

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,papersize={15.5cm,23.5cm}]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesection\arabic{theorem}}

\renewcommand{\proofname}{\upshape\bfseries Proof}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath\blacksquare}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{ABC}
    blablabla
    \section{ONE}
    \begin{theorem}
        dddd
    \end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
    It is clear.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

And the output is as follows.

[image]

---

**By the way, the chapter numbers should not be roman since the prefixes in section numbers are arabic. Also, it's not necessary to add dots after section numbers since there are no dots after chapter numbers.**

Comment: Can you link to more information on the roman/arabic prefixes

Comment: @Brandon I don't know what you want and how to link to my mind...

Comment: is there any reason other than that they are different?

Comment: In fact, the chapter numbers and the prefixes in section numbers should be the same since they refer to the same object.